Code exiting with segmentation fault following string-to-int conversion implementation in ASM
As stated in my title, I am using the following code to take an input and convert it to an integer, terminating at a non-numerical character. It compiles nicely, but does not want to run. Instead it's returning a "segmentation fault(core dumped)".
Where is my mistake, and how would I fix it?
I am currently compiling into ELF-format using NASM for my linux computer, if that helps at all. Thanks in advance (sorry for not having comments).
section .text

global _start
_start:

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov edx, lenUsrMsg
mov ecx, usrMsg
int 0x80

mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 2
mov ecx, num
mov edx, 8
int 80h

mov ecx, num
mov edi, ecx
xor eax, eax

atoi:
xor eax,eax
.next:
movzx ecx, byte [edi]
sub ecx, '0'
jb .done
cmp ecx, 9
ja .done


imul eaX, 10
ADD EAX, ecx
inc edi
jmp .next

.done:
ret

mov si, 10

print_loop:
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, star
mov edx, 1
int 0x80

dec si
jnz print_loop

mov al, 4
mov bl, 1
mov ecx, endl
mov edx, 1
int 80h

end:
mov eax, 1
xor ebx,ebx
int 0x80

section .data
usrMsg db 'Please specify amount of stars 1-9:'
lenUsrMsg equ $-usrMsg
star db '*'
num db 5
endl db 0xa

the program worked in a previous version, where only single-digit numbers were allowed but it has been breaking when I tried to implement the AtoI function to convert a sting to an int. the mov si, 10 is a stand-in that I used to try and diagnose the problem.

mov si, 10 is immediately after a retn and there's no label addressing the mov. That means this instruction can never be reached and is useless.

num db 5 does not do what I think you think it does (you know, no comments and all). That allocates a single byte of value 5, you probably wanted a buffer of length 5. Use num resb 5 instead. The fault is likely because you try to ret from _start and you can't do that. I assume you accidentally put that ret there because it makes no sense.

I put it there to return from atoi but i'll remove it and see how it goes, @Jester

ALSO i forgot to mention, but i did mean to have num default to 5, but num db 5 probably only allocates one byte, set to 5. I'll change it to num resb 8 instead.

You don't call atoi so you can't ret from there.

I see. So remove ret and change num db 5 should fix.

Also obviously you always print 10 stars, but yeah, it should fix the crash.

yeah well, at least it works now! I added full functionality, as well as an err catch in case the first character is non-numerical.

I found a fix. edit
imul eaX, 10
ADD EAX, ecx
inc edi
jmp .next

.done:
ret

to...
imul eaX, 10
ADD EAX, ecx
inc edi
jmp .next

.done:

removing the ret. then change
mov si, 10

print_loop:

to, the much more productive answer of:
mov esi, eax

print_loop:

don't forget to change dec si to dec esi.
the last short fix is to move num db 5 to section .bss and change it to num resb 8.
thanks to Jester for helping me get these fixes.

Or you could have just done mov esi, eax. Don't see the reason to go through num or ebp.

well i'm a tad bit stupid and didn't know you could do that, as if I just did mov ebp, eax i would get an error. will fix.

mov ebp, eax is also valid and should not produce any error.
